# Simple webcam server

Tags: linux, windows

I am looking for a simple solution to turn a standard webcam on a Windows or Linux PC into a source for webcam images in a website hosted on another machine. Ideally it implements a minimal web server, sitting idle until an image is requested by a browser visiting the site.

The various solutions I found sofar seem to be continuously reading images from the webcam and writing things out to disk, seriously impacting the overall performance of the host PC. This is not desirable in my application, as the host PC's are also performing other tasks.

Any suggestions or pointers to home-grown solutions?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/) - it can stream image over the web, including [http streaming](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch05.html).